# Modifying project with multiple solutions files and multiple project files referencing each other

Tags: visual-studio-2012, setup-project, solution

I have a project structure like -

```
proj_Main
    proj_A(directory) 
         somefile.cs(etc.)
         proj_A.csproj

    proj_B(dir)
         somefile.cs
         proj_B.csproj

    proj_C(dir)
         somefile.cs
         proj_C.csproj

    proj_D(dir)
         somefile.cs
         proj_D.csproj

    proj_Main(dir)
         other dirs etc.
         some.cs files
         proj_Main.csproj
         proj_Main.csproj.user
         proj_Main2010.csproj
         proj_Main2010.csproj.user
         proj_Main2010.v11.suo

    proj_A.sln
    proj_B.sln
    proj_C.sln
    proj_D.sln
    proj_Main.sln
    proj_Main2010.sln
```

(There are actually more than 10 solutions inside it, to keep it simple, I have depicted 4 above.)

While opening it in VS 2012 I have opened proj_Main2010.sln and it shows other linked projects with it, opens them inside the solution. This proj_Main refers the dll of other projects from those other projects. So far fine.

Now I have to modify the code from all project files, but if I do that, the previously referenced classes and code stops working, and throws errors of all sort -

```
  Error 2   The type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am not sure, If this is the correct way to depict the scenario, my apologies for that.

My problem is, I am not sure If I am opening the right file to work on this solution or if I am trying to modify the files safely.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

p.s. I also have a setup project in it ( but I guess its related to deploying an application not useful while developing /redeveloping it)

Comment: Have you got a sample solution which demonstrates this behaviour? I would like to understand the type of references and exactly when the error happens, which is usually due to missing assemblies, improper using declaratives ... but your problem sounds different.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use project references? And if you need to use binary references can you switch over from binary references to using NuGet packages for each of the individual projects (i.e. Proj_A, Proj_B, etc?